# How can I get rid of union symbol in Latex when it's supposed to be whitespace

Tags: formatting, latex

Hi all I have code in latex here,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL,morekeywords={PREFIX,java,rdf,rdfs,url}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily, showspaces=flase]
    WHERE {?s og:type "Internally displaced"};
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But when I output the pdf, it is something like this, how can I get rid of the union symbol?

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bflRJ.png)

Comment: Cross-network duplicate: [Strange character when using `listings` package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54183/5764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `showstringspaces=false` instead of `showspaces=false`.